# React no guarda data en el state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy consumiendo recursos de una API y almacenandolos en los states, especificamente en listadoItems: [] pero por cuando actualizo los states con la data proveniente de la api no me pasan los valores..devolviendome un array vacio  en listadoItems: [] estoy trabajando con context api, siento que en this.setState no estoy pasando bien la ruta para hacer el feed de la data al array

```
export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        store: {
            listadoItems: [],
            carroItems: []
        }
        ,
        action: {
            addItem: this.addItem,
            showModal: this.showModal
        }

    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getInfo();
}

getInfo = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.status);
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('recibe: ', data);
        this.setState({
            listadoItems: data
        })
        console.log('listado: ', this.state.store.listadoItems);
    })
}
```

Comment: A parte de la respuesta que dieron ya, te añadiría que el state se actualiza de manera asíncrona, por lo que es posible que tu `console.log` aún no te muestre datos, para asegurarte mejor ejecuta el `console.log` en el callback del `setState`, así: `this.setState({ store: { listadoItems: data } }, () => { console.log(this.state.store.listadoItems) })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu constructor estás asignando la propiedad `listadoItems` dentro de la propiedad `store` y esta última al `state`. En el uso de `setState` estás omitiendo la propiedad `store`, por lo tanto le estas agregando al **state** del componente la propiedad `listadoItems`. Como resultado te debería estar quedando un **state** con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    store: {
        listadoItems: [],
        carroItems: []
    }
    ,
    action: {
        addItem: this.addItem,
        showModal: this.showModal
    },
    listadoItems: [/*tus datos*/]
}
```

Deberías cambiar la línea donde estableces el **state** a:

```
var _store = { store: { listadoItems: data }}
this.setState(_store)
```